# Jquery counter shows zero after reset

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JQuery to set up a counter from 60 and it is working great. except when it counts down the first round and reaches zero, when I reset it, it first shows zero and the starts from 60 again. I want it to immediately start from 60 after resetting.any ideas?
here is my code(it is a sample code that gives the same result as my original code)

```js
    $("#Resend-confirm-phone-number-code").hide();
    var count = 60,
        timer = setInterval(function () {
            $("#counter").html(--count);
            if (count == 0) {
                clearInterval(timer);
                $("#resend").fadeOut("fast", function () { });
                $("#Resend-confirm-phone-number-code").fadeIn("fast", function () { });
            }
        },
            1000);
    $("#resend").show();
    function aliAsghar() {
        $("#Resend-confirm-phone-number-code").hide();
        var count = 60,
            timer = setInterval(function () {
                $("#counter").html(--count);
                if (count == 0) {
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    $("#resend").fadeOut("fast", function () { });
                    $("#Resend-confirm-phone-number-code").fadeIn("fast", function () { });
                }
            },
                1000);
        $("#resend").show();
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="newRegister-addCode" id="confirmPhoneNumberForm-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="newRegister-helpText">
            <p>
                enter the code
            </p>
        </div>
        <form class="newRegister-formBox" method="Post" id="confirmPhoneNumberForm" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="formElement newRegister-input">
                <i class="fa fa-key"></i>
                <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="code" id="code" class="form-control persianDigitInput"
                    placeholder="enter the code">
                <div class="newRegister-alarmText">
                    
                    <p id="resend"> seconds left<span id="counter" >60</span></p>  
                    
                    <button class="animateBtn" type="button" id="Resend-confirm-phone-number-code" style="Display:none; " onclick="aliAsghar()">
                        <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
                        send again
                    </button>
    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="newRegister-button">
                <button type="button" id="send-confirm-phone-number-code" class="animateBtn" >
                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                    submit
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle for the same?

Comment: @SmitRaval it's always preferrable to have a runnable snippet here, instead of off-site.

Comment: I have added the html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the issue by immediately updating the HTML of the element with the `count` value when the function is first called, and before the first iteration of the interval has happened.

You can then DRY up the logic by simply calling `aliAsghar()` when the page loads, instead of having the same logic copied in to the page twice.

Note the use of an unobtrusive event handler over `on*` event attributes in the HTML which should be avoided where possible, and also the removal of the empty callback functions on the `fadeX()` calls, which are not mandatory.

```js
function aliAsghar() {
  $("#Resend-confirm-phone-number-code").hide();
  var count = 5; // set to 5 just to speed up testing
  $("#counter").html(count);

  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    $("#counter").html(--count);
    if (count == 0) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      $("#resend").fadeOut("fast");
      $("#Resend-confirm-phone-number-code").fadeIn("fast");
    }
  }, 1000);
  $("#resend").show();
}

aliAsghar(); // onload
$('#Resend-confirm-phone-number-code').click(function() {
  aliAsghar();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="newRegister-addCode" id="confirmPhoneNumberForm-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="newRegister-helpText">
    <p>
      enter the code
    </p>
  </div>
  <form class="newRegister-formBox" method="Post" id="confirmPhoneNumberForm" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="formElement newRegister-input">
      <i class="fa fa-key"></i>
      <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="code" id="code" class="form-control persianDigitInput" placeholder="enter the code">
      <div class="newRegister-alarmText">
        <p id="resend"> seconds left<span id="counter">60</span></p>
        <button class="animateBtn" type="button" id="Resend-confirm-phone-number-code" style="Display:none;">
          <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
          send again
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="newRegister-button">
      <button type="button" id="send-confirm-phone-number-code" class="animateBtn">
        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
        submit
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply set: `$('#counter').text( "60" );`

```js
$("#Resend-confirm-phone-number-code").hide();
$('#counter').text( "60" );
var count = 60,
    timer = setInterval(function () {
        $("#counter").html(--count);
        if (count == 0) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            $("#resend").fadeOut("fast", function () { });
            $("#Resend-confirm-phone-number-code").fadeIn("fast", function () { });
        }
    },
        1000);
$("#resend").show();
function aliAsghar() {
    $("#Resend-confirm-phone-number-code").hide();
    $('#counter').text( "60" );
    var count = 60,
        timer = setInterval(function () {
            $("#counter").html(--count);
            if (count == 0) {
                clearInterval(timer);
                $("#resend").fadeOut("fast", function () { });
                $("#Resend-confirm-phone-number-code").fadeIn("fast", function () { });
            }
        },
            1000);
    $("#resend").show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="newRegister-addCode" id="confirmPhoneNumberForm-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="newRegister-helpText">
        <p>
            enter the code
        </p>
    </div>
    <form class="newRegister-formBox" method="Post" id="confirmPhoneNumberForm" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="formElement newRegister-input">
            <i class="fa fa-key"></i>
            <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="code" id="code" class="form-control persianDigitInput"
                placeholder="enter the code">
            <div class="newRegister-alarmText">

                <p id="resend"> seconds left<span id="counter" ></span></p>  

                <button class="animateBtn" type="button" id="Resend-confirm-phone-number-code" style="Display:none; " onclick="aliAsghar()">
                    <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
                    send again
                </button>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="newRegister-button">
            <button type="button" id="send-confirm-phone-number-code" class="animateBtn" >
                <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                submit
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

To simplify your code you can just call the function:

```js
/*$("#Resend-confirm-phone-number-code").hide();
$('#counter').text( "60" );
var count = 60,
    timer = setInterval(function () {
        $("#counter").html(--count);
        if (count == 0) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            $("#resend").fadeOut("fast", function () { });
            $("#Resend-confirm-phone-number-code").fadeIn("fast", function () { });
        }
    },
        1000);
$("#resend").show();*/
aliAsghar();
function aliAsghar() {
    $("#Resend-confirm-phone-number-code").hide();
    $('#counter').text( "60" );
    var count = 60,
        timer = setInterval(function () {
            $("#counter").html(--count);
            if (count == 0) {
                clearInterval(timer);
                $("#resend").fadeOut("fast", function () { });
                $("#Resend-confirm-phone-number-code").fadeIn("fast", function () { });
            }
        },
            1000);
    $("#resend").show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="newRegister-addCode" id="confirmPhoneNumberForm-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="newRegister-helpText">
        <p>
            enter the code
        </p>
    </div>
    <form class="newRegister-formBox" method="Post" id="confirmPhoneNumberForm" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="formElement newRegister-input">
            <i class="fa fa-key"></i>
            <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="code" id="code" class="form-control persianDigitInput"
                placeholder="enter the code">
            <div class="newRegister-alarmText">

                <p id="resend"> seconds left<span id="counter" ></span></p>  

                <button class="animateBtn" type="button" id="Resend-confirm-phone-number-code" style="Display:none; " onclick="aliAsghar()">
                    <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
                    send again
                </button>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="newRegister-button">
            <button type="button" id="send-confirm-phone-number-code" class="animateBtn" >
                <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                submit
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```